Peut-on avoir la subordonnée au présent et la principale au conditionnel?
Bonjour à tous les lecteurs du site!
J'ai vu un exemple similaire sur votre site mais je ne suis pas encore certaine parce que dans l'exemple, on utilisait le verbe "pouvoir". Ce qui n'est pas le cas pour la phrase qui me "torture"
Voici la phrase qui cause le doute dans mon esprit...
"Je préfèrerais partir dans la soirée, si tu acceptes bien"
Dans mon opinion, le conditionnel est très bien utilisé dans la principale car ça donne l'idée d'un désir. Si tu acceptes maintenant, mon désir serait de partir dans la soirée (je me donne le choix)...
Je trouve que le respect de la règle (si + présent = futur ou présent dans la principale) ne donne pas du tout le même "ton" à la phrase.
"Je préférerai partir dans la soirée, si tu acceptes bien."  Me donne comme l'obligation de partir dans la soirée et non pas la préférence.
J'ai épluché mon Grevisse et le Robert, et je n'ai rien trouvé qui collait exactement à mon interrogation.
Merci pour les sources, je dois avoir non pas seulement l'opinion et la réponse mais aussi la/les source(s)!

Le seul truc qui me chatouille, dans les deux exemples, c'est le bien. Si tu veux bien, ok. Si tu acceptes, ok. Mais si tu acceptes bien, un peu bizarre à mon sens. Sinon, la concordances des temps dans les deux cas me semble correspondre à ce qu'on entend.

Je serais enclin à croire que c'est grammatical.

Cause le doute dans mon esprit ➔ Met/sème le doute; Dans mon opinion ➔ À mon avis; désir ➔ choix; Merci pour les sources, je dois avoir non pas seulement l'opinion et la réponse mais aussi la/les source(s)! ➔ J'apprécierais les réponses accompagnées de sources.

Je ne vois pas de problème de concordance de temps ici, par contre je vois un problème de sémantique : comment peut-on exprimer une obligation avec le verbe « préférer » ?


Je préférerai partir dans la soirée, si tu acceptes bien.

Effectivement, comme dit None, le verbe "préférer" ne porte pas de notion d'obligation.
Pour ma part, même si c'est discutable pour d'autres verbes, cette phrase précise ne me va pas, car elle indique que le locuteur connaît déjà sa préférence pour l'avenir, mais que cette préférence ne sera effective qu'à ce moment-là (de la condition). C'est ce que veut dire l'usage du futur simple.
Si cette phrase doit avoir une connotation d'obligation, alors le verbe "préférer" n'est pas à privilégier. On dira par exemple:
J'irai/je compte partir dans la soirée, tant que ça ne te pose pas de problème.
L'obligation (ici ce serait plutôt la certitude, donc l'emploi du mode indicatif) ne va pas avec la condition.
Si une phrase est formulée avec une condition, cela signifie que l'action n'est pas garantie. D'où la règle du conditionnel.
[Je n'ai pas d'autre source que la définition de base des modes indicatif et conditionnel/subjonctif, désolée.]
